# Unable to find cordova-3.5.0.jar file

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I am creating phonegap app for android. For this, I followed all steps from http://phonegap.com/install/ 
My Project is created but didn't get cordova-3.5.0.jar file which I have to add in /libs folder. Can anybody help me how to get this file. I am stuck at this point. Please help me..!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did You Check the jar is added in BuildPath ?

Comment: sorry...didn't get you...!! :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to copy any libraries as the Eclipse project is created during the platform creation.
Please follow this guide step-by-step:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

Answer (score 0):

Try below link.. Then your phonegap should download on phonegap official site only.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Comment: Try this old way. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

Comment: But path setting main important.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) is open source, and the engine powering PhoneGap, the mobile development framework produced by Nitobi and since, purchased by Adobe.

Step for phonegap/cordova setup

1. Install Node
2. npm install -g cordova
3. cordova create project com.yourdomain.project
4. cordova platform add ios android